# Is it Normal to have CPU Usage 20-25% when scrolling a UICollectionView Containing a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating a Chat Message `UICollectionView` containing a `UITextView`. I calculate the cell size according to message Text. When I scroll collection View CPU Usage jumps to 20-25% when scrolling stop it drop down back to 0%. Scrolling is smooth. There is no Lagging when scrolling.  Is it normal behavior of iOS or I am doing something wrong ?

These are consuming most CPU
[image: Fisrt]
[image: Second]

Comment: I don't think it's a problem; the cpu needs to handle the scroll, needs to calculate the height every time a cell is about to be shown, plus internal things like cell reusing and dequeueing; this stuff are done even if your cell's layout is really simple.

Comment: You could profile your code with Instrument's time profiler. Then you could identify which part or your code consumes the CPU time.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner These are consuming most CPU. Please see edited Question
[link](https://i.imgur.com/mu7c72g.png)

[link](https://i.imgur.com/qPDEeqE.png)

Comment: Thanks for adding the time profiles. What I don’t understand is that `performBatchUpdates` is called (so often) during a scroll. It should be called only when you update your collection view, and not when you scroll. Did you select only the scrolling part in your time line?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I am calling `performBatchUpdates` only when new message is added to collectionView

Comment: If `performBatchUpdates` is not called during a scroll, then you did include also the addition of new messages in your profiling, because it is shown there. If you profile only the scrolling, you could better identify what takes most CPU time.